# Dividing by epsilon and taking the limit of epsilon to zero

Tags: probability-theory, proof-writing, epsilon-delta, order-statistics

In deriving the joint distribution of two order statistics, there is the following step (F(x) is the Cumulative Dist Function at x, f(x) is the PDF at x):

$$
F(x-\epsilon)^{n-s}\times[F(x+\epsilon)-F(x-\epsilon)]\times [F(y-\epsilon)-F(x+\epsilon)]^{s-r-1} \times[F(y+\epsilon)-F(y-\epsilon)]\times (1-F(y+\epsilon))^{r-1}
$$
then, we divide by $\epsilon$ and take $\epsilon \to 0$, which yields:
$$
F(x)^{n-s} \times f(x)\times [F(y)-F(x)]^{s-r-1} \times f(y) \times (1-F(y))^{r-1}
$$

since

$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{F(x+\epsilon)-F(x-\epsilon)}{\epsilon} = f(x)
$$

My question is, there are two expressions using this epsilon to get $f(x)$ and $f(y)$, which means that its more like dividing by $\epsilon^2$?
I am confused on this point, is it that we can ignore this since $\epsilon$ is going to zero anyway?

Comment: Yes, you do have to divide by $\epsilon$ twice (though they can be different epsilons).  In effect you are taking the double derivative $\frac{d^2}{dx\,dy}$ and the $\epsilon$s correspond to $\delta x \to 0$ and  $\delta y \to 0$.  But you may have another error of factors of $2$: I would have thought $\displaystyle \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{F(x+\epsilon)-F(x-\epsilon)}{\epsilon} = 2f(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this is wrong; the second expression is essentially the limit of the first expression divided by $\epsilon^2$ (up to two factors of $2$, as Henry pointed out).

Comment: is this implicit in the statement, divide by epsilon and take the limit to zero, or is there an error in the book?

Comment: @dimebucker91: I can't say whether there's an error in the book because sometimes people misunderstand things in books and then paraphrase them incorrectly in asking about them. There's certainly an error in what you say the book says; whether the error is in the book or in your paraphrasing can only be decided if you quote the book verbatim.

Comment: fair enough, its actually from a set of new lecture notes and that is the statement made, I guess it is incorrect.